# Windows10 scaling wrecks height computations

Tags: jquery, html, windows-10

I'm guessing the advice will be 'don't use height()' but let me at least explain the situation:

When trying to figure out why JQuery height() was returning the wrong value, I stumbled across this *recommended* setting in Windows 10 which scales 'APPS' to 150% -- I didn't turn it on, so it must be some kind of default: 
[image]

When that is enabled you can't really use any kind of.height() function, JQuery or otherwise will return 550px, but it is really taking up 932px

Given this HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div style='height:550px;background-color:lime'>abc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I end up with a div of 932px in chrome as proven by the following screenshot.  I checked my zoom factor (ctrl plus / minus) its 100%.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use `window.devicePixelRatio`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getDevicePx()
{
  let px =   window.devicePixelRatio * 550
  alert('true px is ' + px)
}
</script>


<html>
<body>
<div style='height:550px;background-color:lime'>abc</div>
<input type='button' onclick='getDevicePx()' value='clickme'>
</body>
</html>
```